# Pass Object to WCF Service Call C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having difficulty in understanding how to call the following WCF Service.

```
public class Product : Proactive.Product.ProductDataServiceClient
{
    public GetProductSellableResponse getProductSellable(GetProductSellableRequest _GetProductSellableRequest)
    {

        GetProductSellableResponse rep = new GetProductSellableResponse();

        return rep;
    }
}
```

How do I pass the GetProductSellableRequest object to the call? Do I just send the XML?

Comment: It's strange to see Request and Response objects at all in a WCF service. That might be just a matter of naming but better post (part of) the ServiceContract .

Comment: Also it would be good to understand what is your client (C# application or something else)?

Comment: @IgorLabutin it is C#. but we are trying options in JQuery as well

Comment: Good that this is C#. Now I support that we also would like to see the contract (and maybe part of app.config would be useful to see how you expose your WCF service).